Calculating rotation angle of each path on a svg circle chart
https://jsfiddle.net/p4d57e8x/3/
const getArcPath = (start, end, innerRadius, outerRadius) => {
    const startAngle = start * Math.PI * 2;
    const endAngle = end * Math.PI * 2;
    const x1 = innerRadius * Math.sin(startAngle);
    const y1 = innerRadius * -Math.cos(startAngle);
    const x2 = outerRadius * Math.sin(startAngle);
    const y2 = outerRadius * -Math.cos(startAngle);
    const x3 = outerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle);
    const y3 = outerRadius * -Math.cos(endAngle);
    const x4 = innerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle);
    const y4 = innerRadius * -Math.cos(endAngle);
    const bigArc = end - start >= 0.5;
    const outerFlags = bigArc ? '1 1 1' : '0 0 1';
    const innerFlags = bigArc ? '1 1 0' : '1 0 0';
    return `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} A ${outerRadius} ${outerRadius} ${outerFlags} ${x3},${y3} 
        L ${x4},${y4} A ${innerRadius} ${innerRadius} ${innerFlags} ${x1},${y1} Z`;
};

This is the code for the path itself, and all of the paths they create a circle.
I am not sure how to get the rotation angle for each path in the circle (say there is red, green, blue, purple), I've tried many things but this seems more of a math problem more than anything else.
I tried a bunch of random code I found, this for example
const getRotationAngle = (start, end) => {
    const startAngle = start * 360;
    const endAngle = end * 360; 
    return (startAngle + endAngle) / 2;
};

but it doesn't work of course because it's just gibberish for me and I have no idea what I even need to calculate to get the angle.


const {useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo} = React;

const PROGRESS_UNIT = 0.01;
const PROGRESS_TIMEOUT = 5;

const getArcPath = (start, end, innerRadius, outerRadius) => {
    const gap = 0.01; // Adjust this value to control the gap between arcs
    const startAngle = start * Math.PI * 2;
    const endAngle = (end - gap) * Math.PI * 2; // Adjusted end angle
    const x1 = innerRadius * Math.sin(startAngle);
    const y1 = innerRadius * -Math.cos(startAngle);
    const x2 = outerRadius * Math.sin(startAngle);
    const y2 = outerRadius * -Math.cos(startAngle);
    const x3 = outerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle);
    const y3 = outerRadius * -Math.cos(endAngle);
    const x4 = innerRadius * Math.sin(endAngle);
    const y4 = innerRadius * -Math.cos(endAngle);
    const bigArc = end - start - gap >= 0.5;
    const outerFlags = bigArc ? '1 1 1' : '0 0 1';
    const innerFlags = bigArc ? '1 1 0' : '1 0 0';

    return {
        path: `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} A ${outerRadius} ${outerRadius} ${outerFlags} ${x3},${y3} 
        L ${x4},${y4} A ${innerRadius} ${innerRadius} ${innerFlags} ${x1},${y1} Z`,
    };
};



const DonutChart = ({ width, height, items, innerRadius, outerRadius }) => {
    const [visiblePart, setVisiblePart] = useState(0);
    const [rotationAngle, setRotationAngle] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (visiblePart < 1) {
            setTimeout(() => setVisiblePart(visiblePart + PROGRESS_UNIT), PROGRESS_TIMEOUT);
        }
    }, [visiblePart]);



// Usage in DonutChart component
    const segments = useMemo(() => {
        const sum = items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.value, 0);
        let start = 0;
        var starto = 0;
        return items.map((item) => {
            const delta = (item.value / sum) * visiblePart;
            const { path, rotationAngle } = getArcPath(start, start + delta, innerRadius, outerRadius);
            start += delta;
            var deg = (360 / sum) * item.value;
            item._angle  = deg;
            starto+= deg;


            return { ...item, path, angle: deg };
        });
    }, [items, innerRadius, outerRadius, visiblePart]);
    
 React.useEffect(() => {
      setRotationAngle(segments[0].angle)
    }, [segments]) 
    console.log(segments)
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='info'>{rotationAngle}deg /{segments[0].color}</div>
        <div className='pointer'></div>
        <svg width={width} height={height}>
        <g transform={`translate(${width/2},${height/2}) rotate(${rotationAngle})`}>
          {segments.map((segment) => (
            <path 
              key={segment.color} 
              stroke={segment.color} 
              fill={segment.color} 
              d={segment.path} 
            />
          ))}
        </g>
     </svg>
        
      </div>
   );
};

const items = [
    {value: 100, color: 'red'},
  {value: 200, color: 'green'},
  {value: 300, color: 'blue'},
  {value: 150, color: 'purple'},
];

ReactDOM.render(<DonutChart width={500} height={300} items={items} innerRadius={100} outerRadius={140} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
svg {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.pointer {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #2f2f2f;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}
.info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app' />




Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Sorry I was wrong the start and end arguments are relative e.g 0.5=180 degree. However, please explain what the rotation angle is used for. Why not use the start angle?

I am simply trying to get the center angle of a path so that I may rotate and end up on that color, whatever works is my goal.  An example of the usage is<g transform={translate(${width / 2},${height / 2}) rotate(${angle})}>

It seems that you question is difficult to understand. Maybe you can give us an example of something that does not work. In the jsfiddle you link to everything looks fine (I could be wrong), so try adding something that shows how your math is not working -- or maybe better, show an svg element that is placed wrongly.

Here is another jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xbqe93au/28/ I used your code you suggested as well for getting the angle.

Please add you code examples to your question and not to  the comments. external examples may expire.

I cannot believe it is so hard to get the angle of a segment relative to the circle itself. It seems something so simple and yet it isn't, at all apparently...

Your JSFiddle references a 44 KB React solution; there is a 999 Bytes Web Component for it:

I wrote a Dev.to post for it


<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister.min.js"></script>

<pie-chart stroke-width="120" pull="-150" stroke="blue,purple,red,green">
    <style>
      text {
        font-size: 4em;
        text-anchor: middle;
        fill:beige
      }
    </style>
    <slice size="100"></slice>
    <slice size="200"></slice>
    <slice size="300"></slice>
    <slice size="150"></slice>
  </pie-chart>




Well, that's not the issue here

it might not have been the issue, but it sure solves it better =P

In your example the chart is based on the following data:
const items = [
  {value: 100, color: 'red'},
  {value: 200, color: 'green'},
  {value: 300, color: 'blue'},
  {value: 150, color: 'purple'},
];

The total sum of the values is 100+200+300+150 = 750. A full circle has 360 degrees, therefor each segment is:
red:    360/750 * 100 =  48 deg.
green:  360/750 * 200 =  96 deg.
blue:   360/750 * 300 = 144 deg.
purple: 360/750 * 150 =  72 deg.

Let's say that red starts at 0 deg. Then they must each have the following start and end degrees:
red:    start: 0                  end: 48
green:  start: 0+48 = 48          end: 48+96 = 144
blue:   start: 0+48+96 = 144      end: 144+144 = 288
purple: start: 0+48+96+144 = 288  end: 288+72 = 360

In your jsfiddle example you have a <g> element that has a transform attribute. Here, the entire chart is rotated 216 degrees (this is the angle where the red path starts with 12 o'clock as 0 degrees). So, you can add 216 to all the calculations that I just did (or set the rotation to zero).
Update
So, here is an example of how the segments can be calculated. You already know the method reduce() from the calculation of the sum. But here I also use the method for adding up the amounts (start = 0, and them + the amount of the current item). And then you can see the calculation for the length is 360 / sum * item.amount.


const items = [{
  "amount": 500000,
  "color": "#9092ED"
}, {
  "amount": 100000,
  "color": "#F97F62"
}, {
  "amount": 100000,
  "color": "#00974F"
}];

const g1 = document.getElementById('g1');

const sum = items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.amount, 0);
items.reduce((start, item) => {
  let length = 360 / sum * item.amount;
  g1.innerHTML += `<use href="#c1" stroke="${item.color}"
                   stroke-dasharray="${length} 360"
                   stroke-dashoffset="-${360 / sum * start}" />`;
  return start + item.amount;
}, 0);
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" r="40" stroke-width="20" pathLength="360" fill="none"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="g1" transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-90)"></g>
</svg>



Another example where the sum is used as the pathLength for the circle stroke:


const items = [{
  "amount": 500000,
  "color": "#9092ED"
}, {
  "amount": 100000,
  "color": "#F97F62"
}, {
  "amount": 100000,
  "color": "#00974F"
}];

const g1 = document.getElementById('g1');
const c1 = document.getElementById('c1');

const sum = items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.amount, 0);
c1.setAttribute('pathLength', sum);

items.reduce((start, item) => {
  g1.innerHTML += `<use href="#c1" stroke="${item.color}"
                   stroke-dasharray="${item.amount} ${sum}"
                   stroke-dashoffset="-${start}" />`;
  return start + item.amount;
}, 0);
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" r="40" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="g1" transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-90)"></g>
</svg>




I tried this just now, and it does not work [     {         "amount": 500000,         "color": "#9092ED"     },     {         "amount": 100000,         "color": "#F97F62"     },     {         "amount": 100000,         "color": "#00974F"     } ] I get 257 for the first color, 308 for second, 360 for the last,   var start = 0;     for (var player of players) {         var deg = (360 / sum) * player.amount         start+= deg;         player._angle = start;     } And it's never even close to being right

I don't know why do you bother when you know that is not what is being asked. I don't need a stroke for anything, the rotation is for the  itself so that it may appear on whatever segment I want it on.

I know, but I was just trying to give an example of the calculation. Never mind about the stroke and the stroke-dasharray.

Right, but I have tested it and it does not work. I've put out a comment above when I did test it, I put it on jsfiddle utilizing your code as well showing what I'm trying to achieve. https://jsfiddle.net/xbqe93au/28/
